# Arithmetic expression is 0 instead of 1

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int a,b,c;
  cin >> a >> b >> c;
  cout << a/b*c;
  return 0;
}
```

For a=5 b=10 c=2 the output gives 0 which is obviously wrong.
As far as I understood << / * are binary operators / and * "bond" stronger than << and for / and * it is calculated from the left to right so first 5 is devided by 10, then the result (0.5) is multiplicated with 2 which is 1 and that is delivered by << to cout.

So can anyone give me an explanation for that result (0)?

Comment: you should cast your division to double to get your expected result

Comment: ah int makes 0.5 to 0

Comment: yes i just noticed i am an idiot
ty

Comment: If you want to keep it integer arithmetic, you could rearrange your expression: `c*a/b`. Of course, you'll get truncation when `c*a` is not divisible by `b`.

Comment: @Chromo sapiens: Not exactly. There never was a `0.5` in your operation. When you divide integers, you immediately get a whole quotient and a reminder. `5 / 10` gives `0` quotient. `5 % 10` gives `5` as a remainder.

Answer (score 2):

This is the integer division issue: if `a==5` and `b==10`, then `a/b==0`.

See the standard, **Multiplicative operators [expr.mul]**

> For
>   integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of integer rounding. When integer division is performed any fractional remainder is simply cut off. So `2 / 3 == 0`.

To keep the results as accurate convert use doubles or convert the variables to doubles in the expression. So something like this

```
static_cast<int>(static_cast<double>(a) / static_cast<double>(b) * static_cast<double>(c))
```

will result in the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

No its not wrong

Since all variables are integers.

5/10 is 0 in the integer world and that multiplied with 2 is still 0

9/10 is also 0 but 11/10 is 1

if you want something useful from this declare the variables as double instead or IOW:

```
int main() {
  double a,b,c;
  cin >> a >> b >> c;
  cout << a/b*c;
  return 0;
}
```